# Get data from Tkinter Python to Database MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I'm back with some trouble ._.
Can some one help me ? I have trouble when I want to put some data to my database from `Tkinter Entry(Widgets)`.
I have table "book" in my database, I want to put some data from `tkinter` to my table "book".
I already use `get` but I don't get anything in my programs
can someone help me for this ?

Thank you. oh yeah, this is my script :)

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector as mc
import tkinter.messagebox as tm


def put(*args):
    e_code = i_code.get()
    e_name = i_name.get()
    e_price = i_price.get()
    conn = mc.connect(user="root", password="mypassword", host="localhost", database="book_test")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into book(book_code, book_name, book_price) values('"+e_code+"', '"+e_name+"', '"+e_price+"')")
    conn.close()



root = Tk()
root.title("GET DATA")

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()

i_code = IntVar()
i_name = StringVar()
i_price = IntVar()


codeEntry = Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=i_code)
nameEntry = Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=i_name)
priceEntry = Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=i_price)

codeEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
nameEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
priceEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(mainframe, text='Book Code').grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(mainframe, text='Book Name').grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(mainframe, text='Book Price').grid(row=2, column=0)

Button(mainframe, text="Insert", command=put).grid(row=3, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

i got this error, can someone help me ? or give me the clue hahaha ._.

`Exception in Tkinter callback`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__return self.func(*args)`
`File "/home/oncom/PycharmProjects/guiProject/fkinggetdata.py", line 13, in put`
`cur.execute("insert into book(book_code, book_name, book_price) values('"+e_code+"', '"+e_name+"', '"+e_price+"')")`
`TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Do you get an error message?

Comment: wait, i will hide try and exception.....

Comment: @scotty3785 dude you can check my edited question for more information hehehe -_-
thank you before

Answer (score 3):

You have everything in error message.

You can't concatenate string and number. You have to convert number into string `str(i_code)` and `str(i_price)` before you concatenate

```
"... values('" + str(e_code) + "', '" + e_name + "', '" + str(e_price) + "')"
```

But you should use `?` in SQL query and tuple with values as second argument

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO book(book_code, book_name, book_price) VALUES('?', '?', '?')", (e_code, e_name, e_price) )
```

It is prefered method. It prevents SQL injection.

Comment: Using ? is the correct way to do it. 
PS you have a typo VALUSE should be VALUES.

Comment: @scotty3785 yes, typo when I change to uppercase to make it more readable :)

Comment: @furas thanks dude for your answer, but in my table book it still empty when i using str(e_code) but if i using values('?', '?', '?') i got error `Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`. oh yeah in my table book, book_code is int auto_increment, book_name is varchar and book price is int ._. do you know what happend while i using +str(e_code)+ no any error but my table still empty -_- Thank you ;;)

Comment: `values('?', '?', '?')` expects tuple with 3 arguments - maybe you have more or less then 3 arugments. If `book_code` is `int auto_increment` then you shouldn't set it manually so skip it. After `execute()` you should do `commit()` because `commit()` sends query to database (and saves data in database).